# How to create bridge for KVM without link on eth* and give access to internet

Tags: iptables, virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

i have a task, where i should create br1 without link to eth* and give to this br1 access to internet. 
I have CentOS7. I have created the interface br1:

```
DEVICE=br1
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

In iptables i have written this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.122.1
```

192.168.122.1 for example my main interface, that has access to internet.

My question: it is enough for get access to internet from my virtual machine on KVM, or i need do something else. 
Maybe i need some FORWARD rules. Because virbr0 interface working, but my br1 no.

Comment: Please show FORWARD iptables rules.

Comment: No rule. What in the "FORWARD" i should add ?

Comment: Why not just use libvirt's nat network

Comment: because, i have a task, do not use default network of virbr0. i should create bridge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use masquerading to assign NAT on Linux server instead SNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

To allow forwarding packets to the Internet:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

To allow forwarding packets from the Internet:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o virbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

To allow forwarding packets between two virtual networks:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i br1 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o br1 -j ACCEPT
```

Add default `deny` rule for forwarding other packets. It drops all unwanted connections from internet to your local networks:

```
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

Don't forget enable forwarding by command:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```